# Synchronizing Contacts and Bookmarks in Ubuntu One Failure

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, contacts, bookmarks

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 with all upgrades. Ubuntu One will sync files very good but it will not sync the contacts or bookmarks. I have done the troubleshooting steps of removing all mention of couchdb from the passwords list, installed the bindwood add-on in Firefox, and even reinstalled couchdb. It still will only sync the files. Anybody know what should be done? I am not a seasoned veteran of Linux but am learning, so am looking to those that know how this works for your input.

This is what happens when I try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17263/synchronizing-contacts-and-bookmarks-in-ubuntu-one-failure/17283#17283).

```
dendox@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ killall beam.smp beam
beam.smp: no process found
dendox@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ 
dendox@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ rm ~/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini
dendox@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ 
dendox@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ dbus-send --session --dest=org.desktopcouch.CouchDB --print-reply --type=method_call / org.desktopcouch.CouchDB.getPort
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Answer (score 4):

In order reset desktopcouch/couchdb to a known state please verify the following:

1. There are no DesktopCouch entries in gnome-keyring (seahorse frontend)
2. There are no desktopcouch-service processes running:

   /usr/lib/desktopcouch/desktopcouch-stop

   killall desktopcouch-service
3. There is no config file for couchdb - ~/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini
4. There is no bookmark file in ~/.local/share/desktop-couch/couchdb.html [LP:668409](https://launchpad.net/bugs/668409)

After this please try running desktop-couch directly:

/usr/lib/desktopcouch/desktopcouch-service

This should print out a lot of messages but in the end it should start replicating the databases. In case the startup fails completely (i.e. with python stack trace or something that looks like error) then something else may be broken and a deeper investigation will be required.

Answer (score 0):

**Syncing Contacts:**

If you are on Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick) or higher,please make sure you have the latest updates. If you have the latest updates installed and contacts still aren't syncing, then you can try these steps.

1. Open System->Preferences->Passwords and Encryption Keys
2. Right-click on any "Desktopcouch" entries and select "Delete"
3. Open Applications->Accessories->Terminal and run:

   `killall beam.smp beam`

   `rm ~/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini`

   `dbus-send --session --dest=org.desktopcouch.CouchDB --print-reply --type=method_call / org.desktopcouch.CouchDB.getPort`

You'll need to wait about ten minutes for syncing to complete.

**[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyArentMyContactsSyncing)**

**Note:**

- In your browser and mail tools export your bookmarks and contacts to a file under the ubuntu-one folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when I run what you have posted:

dendox@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ killall beam.smp beam
beam.smp: no process found
dendox@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ 
dendox@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ rm ~/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini
dendox@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ 
dendox@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ dbus-send --session --dest=org.desktopcouch.CouchDB --print-reply --type=method_call / org.desktopcouch.CouchDB.getPort
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, the way this site works is you keep continuously editing your question with things you have tried. I've gone ahead and edited it for you so you can see how it works. Feel free to delete this answer. See here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work